# what does "it is to be" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

i am learning this [course](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuyk1nLMhRm6WkyV2sFP81ENNnsnydcm_).

the teacher is [saying](https://youtu.be/QzN4cSH71D0?t=2922)

> what this course is about and also what it is to be a CS230 student in
>   fall 2018.

what does "it is to be" here mean?

Answer (score 1):

In this example,

> what this course is about and also what it is to be a CS230 student in fall 2018.

The example is a sentence fragment. It is appropriate to use a fragment like this in a list of bullet points, or a brief answer to a question.   Only the second part of the sentence relates to your question:

> (**what it is**) (**to be a CS230 student in fall 2018.**)

You can simplify this to:

> (what it is) (to be a student) (in this class).

Grammatically, you can check the meaning of this sentence by inversion:

(To be a student) (in this class) (is what)?

This question is asking **what does being a student in this class** mean.

- There are many classes — so how is being a student in this class different?
- How can we define "being a student" or "the condition of being a student" or "studenthood" in this class?

Grammatically, this might have the following answers:

> (To be a student in this class) is a big time commitment.   [*defines how much work the students will be doing*]
>
> (To be a student in this class) is an honor.   [*defines something about the condition of being a student -- a simple noun*]
>
> (To be a student in this class) is to be ethical.    [*defines the expected character, or future behavior of the students*]
>
> (To be a student in this class) is the result of your good results on an entrance exam.   [*defines how the students arrived at this condition, or this class*]